# Routing will load pages as plaintext html with no css. [node js server]

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Heads up, I'm new to javascript. So, I'm trying to set up a basic routing for my pages. It works, but the css files don't seem to load on the pages. However, if I click on the (e.g.) `index.html` file, it gets displayed normally on the browser. For reference, my `routes.js` file looks like this:

```
const url = require('url');
let fs = require('fs');

html = {
    render(path, response) {
        fs.readFile(path, null, function (error, data) {
            if (error) {
                response.writeHead(404);
                respone.write('file not found');
            } else {
                response.write(data);
            }
            response.end();
        });
    }
}

module.exports = {
    handleRequest(request, response) {
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/html'
        });

        let path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

        switch (path) {
            case '/':
                html.render('../authorization_code/public/landing_page.html', response);
                break;
            case '/about':
                html.render('../components/about.html', response);
                break;
            default:
                response.writeHead(404);
                response.write('Route not found');
                response.end();
        }
    }
}
```

and my server is set-up like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
const url = require('url');
let router = require('./routes');

let handleRequest = (request, response) => {
  response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html'
  });

};

http.createServer(router.handleRequest).listen(8888);
```

Like I said, if I directly open a `.html` file, the css appears like it should, so it's not that I'm referencing the stylesheet in a wrong way. Is the problem on my routing or on the server creation? Should I add something about including again and loading the css files somewhere?

PS: If there's a way to improve the title to reflect my problem, please say so.

Comment: "Is the problem on my routing"  — You haven't written a route that would serve the CSS.

Comment: If you must reinvent the wheel (I'd simply use [express](https://expressjs.com/) instead), you need to check if the client is requesting a static file first. Append `path` to your public folder path, check if the resulting file exists, and if so, send it back. Note that a standard web server also sets all kinds of headers, like Content-Type, Content-Length, etc. If this is basically an exercise, or a way of learning server-side js, go ahead. But otherwise, use express.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the reply. I also read the linked question, but I didn't really understand to be honest. I understand the way the requests are sent to and from the server, but since I'm linking the stylesheet in my html file, how is that not enough? Why should I also make routes for it, and does that mean that I should make a route for every existing css file I'm using?

Comment: @neonpeach — A link just tells the web browser that there is some CSS at a particular URL. If your server doesn't know how to respond to that URL with the data you want, then the link is a lie.

Comment: @ChrisG I actually started this following a node js tutorial online and then tried t tailor it to my needs, but I guess I should've researched it a bit more first- express seems like a much simpler and clear solution. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said, it depends on what your primary goal is: a) build a website b) learn how HTTP communication works c) learn node. If your goal is a), then use express.

Comment: Like I said previously, dropping the CSS in a folder isn't enough; if you write your own web server you need to instruct it to actually serve these files. You do not need to write a separate route for each file, you need to do what I suggested in my first comment. I.e. Go from 1) browser requests `localhost:8888/style.css` to 2) path is `/style.css` to 3) potential file is `d:/www/test/public/style.css` to 4) file exists, -> send it back